# Bootstrap login colour component

Tags: css, layout, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have got login with class from **bootstrap**:

```
<p class="h4 mb-4">Sign in</p>
<h5 class="card-header info-color white-text text-center py-4" >Sign in</h5>
```

But instead to got color as below:

[image]

My logins looks as:
[image]

Im using **Bootstrap v4.3.1** (created new project with Visual Studio 2017)

Comment: you need to add `bg-info text-white` instead of `info-color`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can chnage the class of `white-text` to `text-white` and for background-color add `bg-primary` and also add code for custom color.

```css
.bg-custom{
  background-color:#33b5e5 !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<h3>Default color</h3>
<h5 class="card-header bg-primary text-white text-center py-4" >Sign in</h5>
<hr/>
<h3>Custom color</h3>
<h5 class="card-header bg-custom text-white text-center py-4" >Sign in</h5>
<hr/>
<h3>With inline css</h3>
<h5 class="card-header text-white text-center py-4" style="background-color:#33b5e5">Sign in</h5>
```

Comment: can this **.bg-custom** be somewhere put inside *h5 block?*

Comment: yes i put this class inside in `<h5>` tag. but you can also add the inline css @4est

Comment: can you show me how it should looks like?
I have already done it to my **css** but also want to know how do in other way

Answer (score 0):

Please use bg-primary class.

```html
<h5 class="card-header info-color white-text text-center py-4 bg-primary">Sign in</h5>
```

Comment: hi, text is black

Comment: instead of white-text use text-white

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `bg-info text-white` instead of `info-color white-text`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<p class="h4 mb-4">Sign in</p>
<h5 class="card-header bg-info text-white text-center py-4" >Sign in</h5>
```

This is reference [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/colors/#background-color)